# Trying to forward a data form with file to another webservice

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, forwarding

I'm trying to forward a data-form request to another webservice but when I receive the new request in the other webservice, it contains the form data, but not the file data:

```
[+] Forward 1: ImmutableMultiDict([('content', <FileStorage: '0,1.txt' ('text/plain')>)])
[+] Forward 2: ImmutableMultiDict([('content', <FileStorage: 'content' (None)>)])
```

In the code, you can see that the index renders the form. You choose a file, and it sends it to the first webservice (forward1). In this webservice, it tries to send the request.form and the request.files to the second webservice (forward2). But not all the information arrives correctly.

What could be happening?

I have tried this, but this solutions doesn't work for me.
[Forwarding multipart/form-data to different service (python, bottle, requests)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21998009/forwarding-multipart-form-data-to-different-service-python-bottle-requests)

```py
import requests
from flask import Flask, request, url_for
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index(methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    return """<html>
                <form method="post" action="{}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input name="content" type="file" />
                <input type="submit">
                </form>
            </html>""".format(url_for('forward1'))

@app.route('/fw1', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def forward1():
    if request.method == "POST":

        payload = request.form
        files = request.files

        print("[+] Forward 1:", request.files)

        response = requests.request(
            "POST", 
            "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5000/fw2", 
            data=payload, 
            files=files
        )

        return ""

@app.route('/fw2', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def forward2():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("[+] Forward 2:", request.files)
        return ""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below codes

```
response = requests.request(
        "POST", 
        "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5000/fw2", 
        data=payload, 
        files={k: (f.filename, f.stream, f.content_type, f.headers) for k, v in files.items()}
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

By using requests library it is very easy. The example shows multiple file uploads with same key and with other form data as well. The images are coming from a form with the key named '`images`'

```
images = request.files.getlist('images')
files = []
for image in images:
    files.append(("images", (image.filename, image.read(), image.content_type)))
r = requests.post(url=api_urls.insert_face_data_url, data={"apikey": apikey, "faceid": faceid},
                          files=files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are forward one file at a time Then create a file upload, then add it to the request as files.

```
file_payload = {file.name : (file.filename, file.stream, file.content_type, file.headers)}
response = requests.post(
        url=url, 
        data=payload,
        files=file_payload)
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```py
response = requests.request(
    "POST", 
    "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/fw2", 
    data=payload, 
    files={files["file"].name : (files["file"].filename, files["file"].file, files["file"].mimetype)}
)
```